# Conditionally modifying collections inline using Java Streams

Tags: java, java-stream

Java 11 here. I have a 2 `List<Fizzbuzz>` instances, `latest` and `current`. The "latest" list is the list of *latest* Fizzbuzzes, hot off the press. The "current" list is the list of Fizbuzzes that I have in my database. I am comparing these lists.

I need to compare these lists and create a 3rd list, `additions`, which contains any Fizzbuzzes from the `latest` list that are not found inside the `current` list. Its a list of "new" Fizzbuzzes that the database does not have on record.

Furthermore, I need to set each addition's `processedAt` field (`Instant`) to the same current date/time. I'd like to try and accomplish this all inline using the Java Stream API. I can accomplish this the "old fashioned" way:

```
List<Fizzbuzz> latestList = getFromFile();
List<Fizzbuzz> currentList = getFromDatabase();
List<Fizzbuzz> additions = new ArrayList<>();
Instant now = Instant.now();
for (Fizzbuzz latest : latestList) {
    if (!currentList.contains(latest)) {
        latest.setProcessedAt(now);
        additions.add(latest);
    }
}
```

My best attempt using the Java Stream API is:

```
List<Fizzbuzz> latestList = getFromFile();
List<Fizzbuzz> currentList = getFromDatabase();
Instant now = Instant.now();
List<Fizzbuzz> additions = latestList.stream()
    .filter(latest -> !currentList.contains(latest))
    .forEach(addition -> {
        addition.setProcessedAt(now);
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This generates a compiler error because `forEach` doesn't return anything. Can anyone spot where I'm going awry?

Comment: You want `map()` instead of `forEach()`.

Comment: Well then I get a compiler error: "_no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that void conforms to R_". I think because changing it to `.map(addition -> addition.setProcessedAt(now))` doesn't have a return value?

Comment: Yeah, you need to return a value from the `map()`. You can do it with `peek()`, but it's a bit iffy, since it's not really supposed to be modifying things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`Stream.peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek(java.util.function.Consumer)), it allows to apply an operation on each element and doesn't keep the result (if there is any) and resume the stream

```
List<Fizzbuzz> additions = latestList.stream()
    .filter(latest -> !currentList.contains(latest))
    .peek(addition -> addition.setProcessedAt(now))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

To a apply a modifying operation, that would transform the data into something else, you need [`Stream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map(java.util.function.Function))

Answer (score 3):

### A *set operation* and List.forEach()

Streams should not have side effects. Therefore you should not modify any stream element from within a stream operation. So I recommend that you don’t use streams at all for your two requirements.

```
    List<Fizzbuzz> additions = new ArrayList<>(latestList);
    additions.removeAll(currentList);
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    additions.forEach(addition -> addition.setProcessedAt(now));
```

The first two lines find the fizzbuzzes from `latestList` that are not in `currentList`.  The `removeAll` method is referred to as a *set operation*, not because it works on sets, but because it is used for finding the something like the *set difference* between two collections (in this case two lists). (Other set operations are `addAll()` for a union and `retainAll()` for an intersection.)

Then the last two lines set `processedAt` as required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create Instant as a final variable to use it in lamda expression

Comment: `now` is *effectively final* since it is not being assigned to after the initialization. That’s enough.